# Spring. How to pass some variable to method in service-activator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rss

I am newbie in Spring, but I am trying to understand it. So now I try to create RSS reader, but all examples in Google are overkill and I don't understand them.
So far I have beans xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:feed="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed/spring-integration-feed.xsd">

    <int:channel id="inputRssFeedChannel"/>

    <feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news"
                                  channel="inputRssFeedChannel"
                                  url="http://feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inputRssFeedChannel"
                           ref="rssPrintOutService"
                           method="printRss"/>

    <bean id="rssPrintOutService" class="MyApp.RssHandler"/>

</beans>
```

And RssHandler class:

```
public class RssHandler {
    private static final Logger theLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RssHandler.class);

    public void printRss() {
        System.out.println("gfgfgfgfgffgfgfg");
    }

}
```

The code works correct I get "gfgfgfgfgffgfgfg" every 5 sec. But I cannot understand how to pass some variable (Rss Entry) to RssHandler for processing title, date and etc and print it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration passes the Message that comes from the particular channel to the handler. So you can try something like:

```
public class RssHandler {
    private static final Logger theLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RssHandler.class);

    public void printRss(Message m) { // The Message Object is in the spring integration packages or in the spring core packages depending on the version
        System.out.println(m);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow! Perfect thanks! As I understand now I have to get Synd object and get all my attributes from it, right?